# Router needed for emulator?

Tags: android, apache, emulation

I am having trouble running my Emulator on the development machine. I am using a laptop with a USB Modem. The Emulator can access the internet, but cannot connect to my Apache server on the laptop. In resaearching the problem, I read the router could be the problem, do I need a router before this works, do I have one already? This is my first app and Im not sure where to go from here, below is the code I am using to connect to the Apache server from the App:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:3128/YES_BUTTON.php");
httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

Apache is listening on port 3128.

I do not have a proxy setup or a firewall on the laptop.

Any ideas?

Much Appreciated,
Graeme.

Comment: I don't see a problem so far, based on [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#emulatornetworking). What error message(s) or exception do you get when you try to connect? Can you verify that you can connect locally to port 3128; that is, does `telnet 127.0.0.1 3128` from your laptop return an error? If so, check that Apache is configured to listen on the loopback interface and not just the external IP address.

Comment: Im not actually getting any error's, when I copy http://127.0.0.1:3128:YES_BUTTON.php into the Internet Explorer browser, it works perfect, but when I run the emulator I doesn't make a connection with Apache, I have checked the server access log and there is no connection there, I tried using telnet but DOS does not recognize it, Im prop doing something silly there, where should I run that telnet command from?

Comment: Hey Mike, I fixed the telnet issue and I get an error saying 'Could not open connection to host on port 23', !

Comment: In my http apache config file I had Listen localhost:3128, I have changed that to Listen localhost:80 and tried the telnet 127.0.0.1:3128 and got the same error, even telnet 127.0.0.1 gives me the same error

Comment: If I do telnet 127.0.0.1 3128 I get a new command prompt, but nothing happens, If I type something, nothing is showing and when I press Enter I get a list of errors

Comment: @Graeme, sounds like your Apache configuration is OK, then. I'm out of ideas, unfortunately - maybe someone who has worked more with the Android emulator will know. Are you sure you aren't getting an exception on the emulator when you try to connect? Try putting a try/catch around your HttpClient calls and see if anything is going wrong? If it isn't connecting, you should see a timeout, connection refused, etc...

Comment: One other thing I'd like to suggest: have Apache listen on 0.0.0.0 rather than localhost. It might be that the docs are incorrect and the emulator will try to connect using something that isn't the loopback interface. If this turns out to be true, be careful to firewall off your Apache server so attackers from the outside can't reach it, if you're on a public network.